# Server Error: Access Denied in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to add custom pages by using using SharePoint Designer 2013, but it throws **Server Error: Access Denied** when I try to add a new aspx page or edit aspx page.

I am site owner and have SharePoint admin access, still I couldn't figure out what went wrong and struggling with this issue for a long time.

When I check permissions with my user name.

*Deny | Add and Customize Pages | Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor.*

I have tried with below command in Sharepoint management shell, not helpful.

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false

Comment: The changes may take up to 24 hours to take effect, wait for 24 hrs and if the issue still exists?

Comment: @Allen_MSFT yes, post 24 hours, still the issue exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this issue?
If not, please check which site template you used for your site, and check the user's permissions on the pages library that is used to store the new pages or existing pages.

Then check [the best practices](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24150607-ff54-4ab8-9ba9-d3175286de5f/sharepoint-online-best-practice-how-to-install-sharepoint-designer-for-connecting-to?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing) about how to install SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint Online, make sure you have followed it to install the CUs.

After that, please try again, compare the result.